# Select data from multiple tables with filtering

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have three tables and I need to select data.

The relation between tables is many to many.

Persons

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ema | Green |
| 2 | Tom | Pattison |
| 3 | Ian | Thomson |
| 4 | Emily | Anderson |

Activities

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Music |
| 2 | Cooking |
| 3 | Football |

Persons_activities

| person_id | activity_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

I need to select all from person and activity tables, but only with filtering by activity name.
So, the result when activity is Football  must be the next:

| person_id | first_name | last_name | activity_id | activity_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Tom | Pattison | 2 | Cooking |
| 2 | Tom | Pattison | 3 | Football |
| 3 | Ian | Thomson | 3 | Football |
| 4 | Emily | Anderson | 1 | Music |
| 4 | Emily | Anderson | 2 | Cooking |
| 4 | Emily | Anderson | 3 | Football |

My query looks like next, but it's without filtering and returns all persons.

```
SELECT p.person_id, first_name, last_name, a.activity_id, activity_name FROM persons p 
JOIN persons_activities pa ON p.person_id = pa.person_id 
JOIN activities a ON a.activity_id = pa.activity_id 
ORDER BY p.person_id, a.activity_id;
```

Only persons with person_id that is mapped to activity_id with the activity_name from persons_activities table should be returned. How the right query must look like?

Comment: `WHERE pa.activity_id = 3` ?

Answer (score 0):

So at the risk of not understanding something about your problem I'll suggest the obvious to filter by *activity name* just add a `where` clause

```
SELECT p.person_id, first_name, last_name, a.activity_id, activity_name
FROM persons p 
JOIN persons_activities pa ON p.person_id = pa.person_id 
JOIN activities a ON a.activity_id = pa.activity_id 
WHERE exists (select * from person_activities a where a.person_id=p.id and a.activity_id=3)
ORDER BY p.person_id, a.activity_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in such a case  I'll get only  Football in the activity_name. But I need to select all activities each person who plays football

Comment: @Java I misunderstood, have edited and changed to use `exists`, does that give you what you expect?

Comment: Unfortunately not quite. It also selects only football activity in the results table but needs to select all activities for those who play football.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to see list of all activities of people who has played football:

```
SELECT p.person_id, first_name, last_name, a.activity_id, activity_name FROM persons p 
JOIN persons_activities pa ON p.person_id = pa.person_id 
JOIN activities a ON a.activity_id = pa.activity_id
WHERE p.person_id in (select p.person_id from Persons_activities where activity_id = 3)
ORDER BY p.person_id, a.activity_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, your question is how to properly filter the virtual table that is created using your join query for a given activity_name:

your Query that joins the tables:

```
``
SELECT p.person_id, first_name, last_name, a.activity_id, activity_name FROM persons p 
JOIN persons_activities pa ON p.person_id = pa.person_id 
JOIN activities a ON a.activity_id = pa.activity_id 
ORDER BY p.person_id, a.activity_id;
``
```

Suggestions to filter this virtual table :

1.You can use the `LIKE` clause in a `WHERE` condition in case you only know the value of the column but not the id of it.

Query for filtering activity_name(you don't know the id):

```
``
SELECT p.person_id, first_name, last_name, a.activity_id, activity_name FROM persons p 
JOIN persons_activities pa ON p.person_id = pa.person_id 
JOIN activities a ON a.activity_id = pa.activity_id 
WHERE a.activity_name LIKE '%Football%';
``
```

2.In case you know the id of the particular column you go with that in `WHERE` condition.

Query for filtering activity_name(you know the id):

```
``
SELECT p.person_id, first_name, last_name, a.activity_id, activity_name FROM persons p 
JOIN persons_activities pa ON p.person_id = pa.person_id 
JOIN activities a ON a.activity_id = pa.activity_id 
WHERE a.activity_id=3;
``
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'd tried, but this query selects only football to the results table, not all the activities. The problem is I need to select all persons with all their activities but with filtering by activity name.  
 So, only persons with person_id that is mapped to activity_id with the activity_name from persons_activities table should be returned.

Comment: use a right join where you get all the values are people who are mapped to activities are alone returned.

Comment: kindly edit your question and state what do you mean by filtering in there. Because you need differ from the way you expressed your question.